# how to skip 1st argument but give 2nd argument in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This `createHtmlElement()` function will by default create a `<div>` tag in body with nothing as content dynamically. But if the user does not provide `parentId` argument and skips to `elementName` parameter by using a comma (like this `{ createHtmlElement("", "div", "hello", "append") }`) then it says: **"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': The provided selector is empty."**

```
function createHtmlElement(parentId = "body" , elementName = "div", elementContent = "", choice ="append"){

            let parent = document.querySelector(`${parentId}`) || document.body; //parent element (parentId)
            let newElement = document.createElement(`${elementName}`)//created element (newElementName)
                newElement.textContent = `${elementContent}`;//element content (newElementContent)
            console.log(parent)
            console.log(newElement)
            parent.appendChild(newElement);
        }

        createHtmlElement("body" , "h2", "this is h2 tag")//this works totally fine
        createHtmlElement("", "h2","this is h2 tag")// console says the provided selector is empty
```

Please tell me how can i give a functionality that if i do not give 1st argument but i can give 2nd argument and the function executes normally. because if create 20 or 30 tags and writing "body" in each line it is time consuming and also space consuming
**how can i skip the first argument and give value of 2nd argument?**

Comment: do not pass in "".  if you pass "" js will assign "" to parentID and that is why you get the error.

Comment: They then need to pass in null instead for this to work

Comment: You could add the arguments as an object. You can then specifically give each arument a value or not. And then check in your script if the aruments isset and has a valid value

Comment: pass `null` or `undefined`

Comment: @Aditya Default parameter values are only used when the parameter value is `undefined`, not `null`. https://jsfiddle.net/q3mtr0d4/

Answer (score 2):

Move parentId the end, then you can omit it

```js
function createHtmlElement(elementName = "div", elementContent = "", choice = "append", parentId = "body") {

  let parent = document.querySelector(`${parentId}`) || document.body; //parent element (parentId)
  let newElement = document.createElement(`${elementName}`) //created element (newElementName)
  newElement.textContent = `${elementContent}`; //element content (newElementContent)
  console.log(parent)
  console.log(newElement)
  parent.appendChild(newElement);
}

createHtmlElement("h2", "this is h2 tag", "body") //this works totally fine
createHtmlElement("h2", "this is h2 tag") // now it works
```

If you do not want to move it, you need to pass `undefined`. Please note  `null` will not work

```js
function createHtmlElement(parentId = "body", elementName = "div", elementContent = "", choice = "append") {
  console.log(parentId)
  let parent = document.querySelector(`${parentId}`) || document.body; //parent element (parentId)
  let newElement = document.createElement(`${elementName}`) //created element (newElementName)
  newElement.textContent = `${elementContent}`; //element content (newElementContent)
  console.log(parent)
  console.log(newElement)
  parent.appendChild(newElement);
}

createHtmlElement("body", "h2", "this is h2 tag", "body") //this works totally fine
createHtmlElement(undefined, "h2", "this is h2 tag") // now it works
```

Alternatively pass an object and spread

```js
function createHtmlElement(parms) {
  const { parentId, elementName, elementContent, choice } = parms;
  
  let parent = document.querySelector(`${parentId || "body"}`); // if passed use parentId
  let newElement = document.createElement(`${elementName}`) //created element (newElementName)
  newElement.textContent = `${elementContent}`; //element content (newElementContent)
  console.log(parent)
  console.log(newElement)
  parent.appendChild(newElement);
}

createHtmlElement({"parentId": "body", "elementName":"h2", "elementContent": "this is h2 tag"}) 
createHtmlElement({"elementName":"h2", "elementContent": "this is h2 tag"})
```

Comment: This only "works" because ``document.querySelector(`${null}`)`` won't find an element with tag name `null`, and there's a fallback to `document.body` in the code. Don't do this.

Comment: @Bergi updated to use undefined instead and not recommend that anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass undefined to skip an argument for JavaScript:

```js
function createHtmlElement(parentId = "body", elementName = "div", elementContent = "", choice = "append") {
  console.log(parentId)
}

createHtmlElement(undefined, "h2", "this is h2 tag")
```

Comment: thanks but adding typing undefined is type of passing some value to the parameter

Answer (score 0):

add below line one the first line of your `createHtmlElement` function.

```
if(!parentId){
  parentId = "body"
}
```

```js
function createHtmlElement(parentId = "body", elementName = "div", elementContent = "", choice = "append") {
  if (!parentId) {
    parentId = "body"
  }

  let parent = document.querySelector(`${parentId}`) || document.body; //parent element (parentId)
  let newElement = document.createElement(`${elementName}`) //created element (newElementName)
  newElement.textContent = `${elementContent}`; //element content (newElementContent)
  console.log(parent)
  console.log(newElement)
  parent.appendChild(newElement);
}

createHtmlElement("", "h2", "this is h2 tag") // console says the provided selector is empty
```

However, I would suggest you to change your argument to an object instead of multiple arguments:

```
function createHtmlElement(options) {
  if(!options){ 
    throw new Error("options is missing")
  }
  let parentId = options.parentId || "body" 
  let elementName = options.elementName
  let elementContent = options.elementContent 
  let choice = options.choice
  // following by your logics
}
```

So when you call the function, you can simply do like this instead of enter empty string:

```
createHtmlElement({
  parentId: "body" , //just remove this property if you don't want to do this step
  elementName: "div",
  elementContent: "",
  choice: "append
})
```

This helps you to recognize which argument is for what purpose when you calling the function, especially when you want to use it for so many times, in the future you may forgot the 2nd or 3rd argument is for what purpose then you have to keep scroll back to the function to check what the purpose of argument.

Comment: @mplungjan added code snippet and its working on the first solution, please further elaborate which part isn't working

Comment: Ah, if you KEEP the "" then it works.

Comment: @mplungjan if you want to fully skip the "", you can either put the `parentId` at the last argument, or use the object argument.

Comment: As I did........

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really skip the first argument in JavaScript you can call the function using undefined as the first parameter like so:

```
createHtmlElement(undefined, "h2","this is h2 tag")
```

but that kind of defeats the purpose of not writing  body on each line.

I can think of two relatively simple solutions:

1. Move the parameter to the end so you will be able to skip it (but there will be cases that you will need to define it).
2. Create a helper function that passes in the parameter by default like so:

```js
function createHtmlElementUnderBody(elementName = "div", elementContent = "", choice = "append") {
  createHtmlElement("body", elementName, elementContent, choice);
}
```

(you can change the name of the new function to be more concise)

Comment: 2nd idea is good but check the top answer @mplungjan he showed the answer

Answer (score -2):

In your function, check if `parentId == ""`. If its true just say `parentId = "body"`